# Selenium Web Driver : Verify pulled-out information from other modules

Tags: java, selenium, scripting, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have yet another interesting question.

I have a 'Service Provider' drop-down field on page A under module 1.
Together with the service provider field, I have the address fields (Address, Location, Zip, Country etc.) on page A.

These service providers have its own CRUD page on page B under module 2.
Page B includes the address details of the service provider.

Now if the user selects a service provider on page A, the system shall pull-out its address info from page B(module 2) and displays it on the address fields on page A.

My question is that, is there a way to verify if the displayed address info on page A matches the address info from page B?

Should you need further clarifications on this, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks a lot guys. :)

Comment: Code is worth thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by launching two driver instances at a time.

Here is the logic

```
WebDriver pageA = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver pageB = new FirefoxDriver();
pageA.get("PAGE A URL");
pageB.get("PAGE B URL");

//Using pageA instance select service provider in PAGE A
new Select(pageA.findElement(By.id("serviceProvider"))).selectByVisibleText("Provider");

//using pageB instance get the address the selected service provider.
String addressInPageB = pageB.findElement(By.id("ServiceProviderAdd")).getText();

//Compare above address with pageA address.
String addressInPageA = pageA.findElement(By.id("ServiceProviderAdd")).getText();

if(addressInPageB.equals(addressInPageA)) {
   Pass;
} else {
   Fail;
}
```